# How to show dockWidget at specific position in Qt?

Tags: qt

I want to open my Qt application like as shown below. I have four dockwidgets, one is fixed and others are dockable.

```
 ___________________
|            |mov.  |
| Fixed      |dock  |
| dockWidget |widget|
|____________|______| 
| Mov.   |Movable   |
|dockwid.|dockwidget|
|________|__________|
```

How can I create some settings or code to achieve this?

Can I use .ini file for default settings and user can also save its settings in .ini file? And how?

Here is the screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what you need?

Comment: I am new member, so its not allowed to attcah an image.

Comment: Here is the link for the screenshot. http://i1106.photobucket.com/albums/h369/gurmeetsingh1/dockwidget.png